# Import npm packages in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, requirejs, aurelia

I'm trying to import gpiobutton package in my joystick.ts but i'm not finding the way.

I tried with the usual: var gpio = require 'gpiobutton'
and also with: Import gpiobutton from 'gpiobutton' but nothing worked.

I've seen that I could use 'define' but it-s not working.

My last try was:
    var gpio: any = require('gpio')
but I have "Module gpiobutton has not been loaded yet for context: _ http://requirejs...."

How can I succeed importing this package?

```
import { LogManager, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

// const remote:Electron.Remote =   (<any>window).nodeRequire("electron").remote;
//const remote:Electron.Remote = (<any>window).nodeRequire("electron").remote;

// var gpio = require("odroid-gpio");
let logger = LogManager.getLogger('Joystick');
import { Config } from '../config';

var gpio: any = require('gpiobutton')

export class Joystick {
  constructor(config: Config) {
    if (!config.get('helmet.joystick.hasjoystick')) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        var buttonSpec = { gpiono: 134 };
        var button134 = new gpio.button(buttonSpec);
        button134.activate();
        console.log(button134);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as Gpio from 'gpiobutton';
```

Comment: I get this error: 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/andrea/helmetprova/helmet-app/src/gpiobutton.js'

Comment: are you sure that gpiobutton.js is there? Make sure the file is located in your src directory.

Comment: gpiobutton is node_modules